# React Native how to remove the blue glow outline on input component

Tags: react-native

I have a react native project (react native for macOS) I am using the input component but notice there is a blue outline. Not sure how to remove it. I am using Native base input component which I am told it's using the react native input component. How can I remove the ugly blue outline when focus. I am mainly trying to remove the one that is square

```
import React from 'react';
import {Icon, Input} from 'native-base';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

const SearchBar = () => {
  return (
    <Input
      variant="rounded"
      size="xs"
      // w={{
      //   base: '75%',
      //   md: '25%',
      // }}
      InputLeftElement={
        <Icon
          as={<Ionicons name="ios-search" />}
          size={5}
          ml="2"
          color="muted.400"
        />
      }
      placeholder="Search"
    />
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When using a React native TextInput component the css styling outline: "none" can be used to remove the outline on focus. This can be done by passing it directly into the style prop.

```
<View style={styles.body}>
      <TextInput
        style={{ outline: "none" }}
        placeholder="Text"
        onChangeText={(newText) => setText(newText)}
        value={text}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

However since you are using a custom component you will need to make sure that the styles are passed to the component.